# How to delete objects from NSArray through tableview in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

First of I like to start with I am new to Objective C and this is my first time developing in it. For some reason I got stuck on how to delete objects from my `NSArray` through `my tableview` (with objects in it). Tryed some diffrent things but seems I am a bit stuck... What shall I pu in the code below?

`bookmarks.m`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]withRowAnimation:YES]; 
    [tableView reloadData];    
}
```

`Bookmarks.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "ShowTaskViewController.h"

#import "Bookmark.h"

@interface BookmarksViewController : UITableViewController  <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSArray *bookmarks;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *bookmarks;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tableView doesn't manage your content. You have to do that yourself. When the user taps delete on a row, you have to remove that item from your array and notifiy the table view to delete the cell (with an animation).

I recommend you change your data array into an NSMutableArray. Then you can do this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [bookmarks removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
                     withRowAnimation:YES]; 
}
```

Alternatively you could temporarily create an NSMutableArray.

```
NSMutableArray *mutableBookmarks = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:bookmarks];
[mutableBookmarks removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
self.bookmarks = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableBookmarks];
```